# SQL. Как выбрать первую строку по конкретному столбцу из группы?

Tags: sql

Нужно оставить только первые строки по вхождению занчения city_id
Допустим есть следующая таблица table.

| id | city_id | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 30 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 |
| 5 | 2 | 30 |

Ожидаемый результат:

| id | city_id | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 4 | 2 | 20 |

Answer (score 2):

В таких случаях помогают оконные функции, а именно ROW_NUMBER().

Пишу на MS SQL, в других диалектах функция может называться по-другому(не проверял):

```
SELECT  id,
        city_id,
        "sum"
FROM
(
    SELECT  id,
            city_id,
            "sum",
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY city_id ORDER BY id) AS NUM
    FROM TableName
) AS Subquery
WHERE NUM = 1
```